# Convert a JS array into JSON n display it

Tags: php

I am new in programming i just want that the value i choose in drop downs must retain selected when i click the search button ... 
here is the code

```
<select name="campaigntype" id="campaigntype" class="text dropDownNewsletter" onchange="GetCampaigns()" style="float:left; margin-right:15px;">
    <option value="">Select Campaign</option>
        <option value="1"  >OB Campaign</option>
        <option value="2">Casbo Campaign</option>

  </select>
                    <div id="selected_campaigns" style="float:left">
                    <select name="campaignid" id="campaignid" class="text dropDownNewsletter">

                        <option value="">Select Campaign</option>

                        <?php foreach($campaigns as $key=>$row){?>

                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" <?php if( $row['id'] == $campaign_id) {?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> ><?php echo $row['id'].'-'.$row['title'];?></option>

                        <?php }?>

                     </select>
```

Comment: If the `$campaign_id` is set correctly, the code should work.

Comment: in source of the page, check where `selected="selected"` is printed. Also confirm, the ids are correct.

Comment: The id's are correct but it's not working